# I came across this line in atoi() and couldnt understand what it did

Tags: c, atoi

I have the following code.

```
while (*str != '\0')
{
  digit = *str - '0';
  result = result * radix + digit;
  str++;
}
```

What does `*str -'0'` mean here.?

Comment: What is 'z'-'a' in C? Now is it clear?

Answer (score 3):

It converts the ASCII characters '0' through '9' to the integer values 0 through 9, respectively.   (Obviously, this is only a good idea if you are certain that `*str` actually is one of the characters '0' through '9'.)

Comment: so if my char *str is "string". what will be the first value of digit?

Comment: That is an invalid use of atoi().  Garbage In, Garbage Out.  The Linux man page for atoi() says "atoi() does not detect errors".
But, the strict answer to your question is:  the first value of digit would be the integer value corresponding to 's', minus the integer value corresponding to '0'.

Comment: @RyanV.Bissell Don't read "man", it is bad and full of errors. C11 7.22.1.2 says atoi is equivalent to `(int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)`. C11 7.22.1.4/8 `The strtol..." /--/ "...functions return the converted value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned.`

Comment: Meaning: atoi must have error handling by the C standard. It will safely, deterministically return 0 if you pass `"string"` as parameter, if the C compiler is a conforming implementation.

Answer (score 1):

*str might point to character values from '0' - '9', however, if one were to use simple arithmetic with *str things might not work as expected.  If *str pointed at character '4' and we did '4' + 2 the result would actually be 54 since the ASCII value for '4' is 52.  So by subtracting '0' from *str we are converting the ASCII values to digits.  '4' - '0' + 2 = 6

http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1):

This converts the character value `*str` into an integer, by subtracting the encoded value of the digit `'0'` from the current character. The value of the integer will be in the range 0 through 9.

This works since C guarantees that the digits 0 through 9 are always encoded using adjacent values (i.e. the encoded value of `'1'` is guaranteed to be exactly `'0' + 1`, and so on).

Many seem to think that this somehow "exploits" some fact of ASCII, but this must work for *any* platform where C runs, regardless of the system's native encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The ascii value of the zero is substracted from the char, so in case of a digit the numeral value of that position will be returned.

Comment: It doesn't have to be ASCII. '0' to '9' are always consecutive though.

Comment: What, you think someone is using atoi() against EBCDIC?  :)

Comment: I needed to read twice your comment, i think you are right the position n the IBM encoding should be equal. But ASCII is more common isn't it? And about Unicode, that depends a little of the implmentation.

Comment: so if my char *str is "string". what will be the first value of digit?

Comment: That would return a non helpful value. I'm just now in a train and cannot calculate that in mind. The value of s is 115 and from 0 is 48 so is 115-48=67